# JAXB Marshalling Child Class inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, jaxb

I have an object (Department) which will be the root element.  It has an aggregated object (Employee) which has two specialisations (Manager and FactoryWorker).  If I set Employee to one of the specialised objects then only the Employee object attributes are marshalled.  I'd appreciate any tips.

e.g.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="department")
class Department {
   public Department() {}
   private Employee employee;
   public void setEmployee(final Employee val) {
       this.employee = val;
   }
}

class Employee {
   private Long id;
   public Employee() {}
   //getters and setters
}

class Manager extends Employee {
   public Manager() {}
   private Integer numberOfProjects;
   //getters and setters
}
class FactoryWorker extends Employee {
   public FactoryWorker() {}
   private Boolean worksNights;
   //getters and setters
}
```

Snippet of code only to show marshalling

```
Deparment department = new Department();
FactoryWorker factoryWorker = new FactoryWorker();
factoryWorker.setId(999);
factoryWorker.setWorksNights(true);

JAXBContext jaxBContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Department.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxBContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(department, System.out);
```

JAXB Output: the specialised attribute of factory worker are not there. Just the values in the parent Employee.

```
<department>
   <employee>
      <id>999</id>
    </employee>
</department>
```

Comment: there are way too many typos in the code you pasted

Comment: The freehand code was simply representative of a simple parent / child structure with standard simple getters and setters.    I've updated it anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to do like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Department")
class Department {
    public Department() {}
    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name="Manager", type=Manager.class),
        @XmlElement(name="FactoryWorker", type=FactoryWorker.class)
    })
    private Employee employee;
    public void setEmployee(Employee val) {this.employee = val;}
}
```

which will output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Department>
    <FactoryWorker>
        <id>999</id>
        <worksNights>true</worksNights>
    </FactoryWorker>
</Department>
```

demo: http://ideone.com/Gw07mI

Comment: You welcome; just to be picky in your code, you _might_ want to add the subclasses as additional parameters in the JAXBContext.newInstance() call. I remember (not sure) I had to do that when generating the schema from the annotated classes.

Comment: Thanks For the Answer i was also facing the same issue.
Now i need to unmarshal this xml but i am geting exception like
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "Person"

Comment: @sumit kumar it is probably a better idea to ask a new question about your problem, so you can show your code and full stacktrace